# defcustom: store variable value permanently

Tags: customize, defcustom

When I have a custom variable and a function that changes it's value:

```
(defcustom current-fileset nil "Currently selected fileset" :type 'string)

(defun set-val ()
  (setq current-fileset "value")
  )
```

and call `(set-val)`, the value of `current-fileset` is change until I restart Emacs. How can I store the value permanently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This saves the new value to your init files.

```lisp
(customize-save-variable
 'current-fileset "newvalue")
```

Or

You can copy this to your init file directly

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
 '(current-fileset "newvalue"))
```

... and restart Emacs.